# Where to download deflate.so in apache http server

Tags: apache

I need use gzip in apache which need mod_deflate.so in modules.But I can't find the download address.Could you please help me?
deflate.so is such a file that provides way to open gzip for apache.I can add some code into httpd.conf as flowing:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
<IfModule deflate_module>  
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE     
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary      
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary      
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:pdf|doc|avi|mov|mp3|rm)$ no-gzip dont-vary      
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css      
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript      
</IfModule>
```

There are many 'so' files in `apache/modules` like `mod_dav.so`、`mod_proxy_ftp.so` and so on.But I can't find mod_deflate.so in the file folder.So I need to download it by myself.Unfortunately, I can't find the download address after searching for a long time

Comment: Or could you please send to me directly?Need 64 bit system apache

Comment: Try adding little more explanation about your problem, like what have you tried until now, and what issues are you facing.

Comment: ok.Thank you for your suggestions and I will make more explanation